# Node.js and requirejs undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase, requirejs

I really tried to find the solution on the stackoverflow and google

but I could not find any clear solution.

I am a student and try to make a web application with

js, node.js, bootstrap, firebase, css

actually when I tried to use do something like var firebase = require('firebase');

I always get the message "require is undefined"

these are my package.json

```
{
  "name": "recette",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Recette BCIT GROUP 22 Project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/lewisfang59/recette.git"
  },
  "author": "Group22",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/lewisfang59/recette/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/lewisfang59/recette#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.2.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.4"
  }
}
```

and this is the code that I wanted to use require

```
// using SendGrid's v3 Node.js Library
// https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'xx@gmail.com',
    pass: 'xxx'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'recette.group22@gmail.com',
  to: 'hwan5263@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

this is the code for firebase, same issue.

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "0",
    authDomain: "recmoved",
    databaseURL: "removed!",
    projectId: "foodver",
    storageBucket: "foo",
    messagingSenderId: "22300"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var db = firebase.firestore();
```

I am very new to this area. Please tell me anything I need to add more!

thank you so much!!

Comment: Where is this code part "var firebase = require('firebase'); "

Comment: did you install firebase `npm install --save firebase`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes I did. and I also npm install for nodemailer too

Comment: it should be in the package.json, are you using browserify?

Comment: The code that uses require... are you running it through a build process or just trying to use it straight in the browser?

Comment: @PeterHaddad ohh sorry. I made the project again. Firebase is working with scrip tho... It did not work although i npm install --save firebase

Comment: @james.brndwgn I am running my code with firebase hosting deploy. I am not sure I answered your question.

Comment: He means this [Firebase in Browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase#npm-bundler-browserify-webpack-etc)

Comment: @LeeHwan it doesn't. But I suspect that you aren't using a build system. `require` is a Node feature which browsers can't interpret natively. To use `require` in a browser you need to run your javascript through a compiler such as Webpack, Browserify, etc. (I say use `require` in a browser, but really the compiler will inject the code into your js bundle - it doesn't add support for `require`)

Comment: @james.brndwgn Thank you so much!!!! Now I am clear!

Comment: @PeterHaddad Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` is not available in the browser.

As mentioned by others, consider introducing a build system like Webpack. [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) may also be an option for you.

Comment: I suggest: "`require` is not available _by default_ in the browser."   Also, I would recommend this answer be accepted.